# Showing that $P(W_{t}/\sqrt{t \log(t)}>1+\epsilon)\to0$ when $t\to\infty$, where $(W_t)$ is a Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I have a question about the martingales $\dfrac{e^{W_{t}^2/(1+2t)}}{\sqrt{1+2t}}$.
With use of this martingale I want to show that $P(\dfrac{W_{t}}{\sqrt{t log(t)}}>1+\epsilon)$ goes to $0$ if $t$ goes to infinity. Does anyone have a hint to show this?

Comment: Hint: For every positive $c$, $$P(W_t/\sqrt{(1+2t)\log t}>c)\leqslant P(W_t^2/(1+2t)>c^2\log t)\leqslant e^{-c^2\log t}E(e^{W_t^2/(1+2t)})=t^{-c^2}\sqrt{1+2t}$$ hence $P(W_t/\sqrt{(1+2t)\log t}>c)\to0$ for every $c>1/\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thank you! Why does the second inequality hold? And how can I work to $\sqrt{tlog(t)}$ instead of $(1+2t)log(t)$

Comment: Markov exponential inequality: $P(X\geqslant x)\leqslant e^{-x}E(e^X)$. // Surely you can compare $\sqrt{t\log t}$ and $\sqrt{(1+2t)\log t}$ when $t$ is large, then adjust $c$, no?